# how to add web view cache in external storage on android fragment screen?

Tags: android, android-fragments

> hi i have three fragment tab view, the three tab having web view am trying to add website in my app .. i fragment not supported to getApplicationContext().. plz help me to  add cache in ma activity.

```
import info.androidhive.tabsswipe.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class ServicesFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_services, container, false);
    WebView webView = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.zudioz.com/services.html");
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

return rootView;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use getActivity().getApplicationContext().